# Connecting OneLogin to Azure Ad

Tags: azure, active-directory, office365, azure-active-directory, onelogin

I am trying to connect One Login to office 365 in order to control the users of Azure from One Login. The idea it is that One Login would be the source of trouth and would sync with azure ad. I did the steps on the tutorial to connect to Office 365 described [here](https://support.onelogin.com/hc/en-us/articles/203547084-Provisioning-Users-to-Office-365)

But I still get the errors
When trying to federate

`AADSTS50107: Requested federation realm object 'https://app.onelogin.com/saml/metadata/#REDACTEDNUMBER#' does not exist.`

If I go to this link I can download the file with success.

And I got this error when trying to sync users.

`#NAME REDACTED# could not be provisioned in Office 365 Azure: Error for create or update a user #NAME REDACTED# an error occurred while processing this request.{"odata.error":{"code":"request badrequest","message":{"lang":"en","value":"property userprincipalname is invalid."},"date":"2018-01-03t16:39:08","requestid":"#GUID REDACTED#","values":[{"item":"propertyname","value":"userprincipalname"},{"item":"propertyerrorcode","value":"invalidvalue"}]}}`

Do anyone knows how to solve that, or had similar problem?

Comment: Is DirSync enabled? Also could you try to change metadata URL to an invalid value, wait for some time for it to reflect in O365 and then change it back? Just wondering if it's a glitch when initially setting up the fed metadata URL.

Comment: How can I enable DirSync since I just have Azure AD I don't have an instance of this AD running one any machine.

Comment: Just wanted to know about your DirSync setting being enabled or not based on the link you shared because it's related to how upn claim is mapped.

Comment: It's difficult to know the exact cause without looking at more advanced settings. There are posts with  AADSTS50107 error caused due to subdomain configuration, AAD settings etc. You may have seen this already but does the following links help (https://worktogether.tech/2016/10/23/error-requested-federation-realm-object-does-not-exist/)  (https://serverfault.com/questions/796102/office-365-adfs-authentication-not-working-for-child-domains) (https://shanejacksonitpro.wordpress.com/2015/09/24/cant-login-to-office365-using-single-sign-on-if-upn-uses-sub-domain/comment-page-1/).