# OneLogin Azure AD as a Directory

Tags: azure, active-directory, onelogin

Our organization uses Azure AD and not Microsoft AD DS .
Does OneLogin integrate with Azure active directory as a 'Directory' apart from the traditional on-prem AD DS. Is there any way to use Azure AD as a directory. 
There is an Azure AD application in the applications section, can we use it to import users from Azure AD? Seems like it's an SSO app only and does not do user provisioning/syncing!

Out of desperation, I also tried the Azure AD Connect to sync to a dummy on-prem ADDS to Azure AD and then sync this dummy ADDS to OneLogin, but this seems like a very hackish way to do it and has it's own host of problems.
I'm not able to figure out how to contact support; there is no support email mentioned on the website anywhere.

Not similar to [Connecting OneLogin to Azure Ad](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48153963/connecting-onelogin-to-azure-ad), as I am trying to add Azure Ad as a directory and the aforementioned question is about an error in federation configuration in Office 365 application of OneLogin.

Any help on this would be immensely appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a conversation with OneLogin support, here's a few ways to achieve this paraphrased:

"We are not able to utilise Azure AD as a classic on-premise directory (such as we might use for AD synchronisation using the OneLogin Active Directory Connector)  although customers who pay extra to Microsoft and have enabled LDAP are able to use our "LDAP via SSL" option although this does not allow for any customisation.

We do have plans to deliver some expanded directory offering but there is no release date for this and you can register a vote and add use-case notes for this request using our IDEAS channel. On US based systems you can use the IDEAS button available at the bottom right corner of the administration screen otherwise access https://onelogin.ideas.aha.io,  select your tenant and then login.  Then look at https://onelogin.ideas.aha.io/ideas/IDEAS-I-1488

If you can generate a CSV list of users in AD then you can import users using a CSV file into OneLogin - still a manual process but you may find this less complex than using the on-premise server - see https://onelogin.service-now.com/kb_view.do?sysparm_article=KB0010529

The "Azure AD application in the applications section" is for going in the other direction and is for using SAML 2.0 with OneLogin as an Identity Provider and is used for Microsoft Azure AD tenancies  where there is no Office 365 involved but users need access to other apps installed in Azure AD.

The other mechanism being used is to have Azure AD as a Trusted IdP and then also enable Just-In-Time provisioning.  This allows the Azure AD users to authenticate to Microsoft and then have a SAML assertion sent into OneLogin and dynamically create all the required fields that the classic directory synchronisation might have allowed (see https://onelogin.service-now.com/kb_view.do?sysparm_article=KB0011181)"

I decided to try Just-In-Time provisioning, will update if any blockers!